# Is there an angular 4 npm package for audio management?

Tags: angular, audio, npm, pubnub

I am trying to implement an angular 4 app integrated with PubNub service.
To send signals from one device, 
that would make a sound on other device (mobile).

Is there any npm package for that purpose?

**edit 5.6.18**
here is the demo code without the audio implementation:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hitpf7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK
I found my solution, its a npm package angular 2 module,
that wraps abstractly AudioContext functionality.
So you don't need to worry about finding the right Object to work with.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-audio-context

Answer (score 0):

You better use your built-in service.
I mean, use socket.io, rely all users to your server (why not use Node.js with its express module?) then, listen for an event (like click on a button : `<button (click)="sendMessage()">` ) then simply use the io.emit() method to send a signal to the server which will send a signal to the targeted user.

see this for more explaination on the socket part : https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-socket-io-tutorial/

Comment: I'll update my question, I am at a state that all the events work, i only ask about how to play a note from the mobile device using js/angular